# Is there any numerical data or theorems on the minimum distance between consecutive zeros of the zeta function?

Tags: roots, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Title basically. I'm looking for any results, papers, or data pertaining to the distribution of zeros of the zeta function on the critical line.

Some numerical data which has a max height $T$ and $\min{\delta_N}$ columns would be great.

I'm also only looking at the first 10,000 - 1,000,000 zeros but asymptotic results or anything would be really helpful.

Cheers guys!